# Casting error working with Telerik Just Mock

Tags: c#, mocking, httpcontext, justmock

```
UrlHelper u = new UrlHelper(ControllerContext.RequestContext);
string url = u.Action("Results", new { id = v.VerificationID });
```

This code above is throwing this error below when using Telerik's Just Mock while unit testing.  This error does Not occur when using the website

Unable to cast object of type 'Castle.Proxies.ObjectProxy' to type 'System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest'.

Any ideas?